# How to set vertical and horizontal scrollbar for table?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table under div and i want to set horizontal and vertical scrollbar according to that table

I am unable to set vertical and horizontal scrollbar  according to window size , I want to set scrollbar for my table , when the table goes out of window size then i should be able to go through the table by using scrollbar

here is the code-

```
            var $container = $("#container");
            var $button = $("<button>" + 'xyz' + "</button>");
            $container.prepend($button);
            var table = $("<table>");
            table.append($("<tr><th>column1</th><th>column2</th></tr>"));

           // Button click handler..
           $button.on("click", function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
           var row = $('<tr ><td>' + 'data' + '</td><td>' + "" + '</td> 
           </tr>');

           table.append(row);

           for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {

           var row = $('<tr><td>' + "" + '</td><td>' + 'data' + '</td> 
           </tr>');
           table.append(row);


          $("#table1").html(table);
          }}
          });
```

div content-

```
             <div id="container">
             <div id="table1">
             </div>

             </div>
```

full code- https://jsfiddle.net/gaurav10022/h7eqb209/12/

I want the table scrollbar to get adjust by window size, that is my table scrollbar should behave according to webpage window size.

Comment: I am not clear what you are intending to do. if you remove width of table, like here https://jsfiddle.net/9smy4guh/, there will be scrollbar when it goes out of window screen..

Comment: i want to set scrollbar for my table , when the table goes out of window size then i should be able to go through the table by using scrollbar?

Comment: you can set the default `width` and `height` of `table` and show scroll bar?

Comment: If you want this tell me

Comment: can you please explain me through some code? @lbnelaiq

Comment: Yeah just answering

Comment: yes ,it would be really heplful.

Comment: answered.Check it out

Comment: Make sure you search also. Pretty sure this has been asked and answered in various ways.

Comment: @wazz, i searched but didn't found answer according to my need, can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Add set default width of table and set `overflow:scroll` to it, Working example below,

```js
var $container = $("#container");

// Loop through items in JSON data..
var $button = $("<button>" + 'xyz' + "</button>");
$container.prepend($button);
var table = $("<table>");
table.append($("<tr><th>column1</th><th>column2</th></tr>"));

// Button click handler..
$button.on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    // Replace row HTML..
    //parent row
    var row = $('<tr ><td>' + 'data' + '</td><td>' + "" + '</td></tr>');

    table.append(row);

    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      //child row
      var row = $('<tr><td>' + "" + '</td><td>' + 'data' + '</td></tr>');
      table.append(row);


  $("#table1").html(table);
  }}
  });



  // Show table if it's not already visible..
```

```css
#table2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  
}
#container{
  height:300px;
  overflow:scroll;
  width:150px;
}

#table1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-collapse: collapse;

}

#table1 th {
  //border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}

#table1 td {
  //border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}

#table1 tr {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}


#table2 th {
  //border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}

#table2 td {
  //border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}

#table2 tr {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

button {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="table1">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I want to scroll table only, i want scrollbar for table , not like this?

Comment: Edited the answer check it.